# Unit Testing for Filtered set of results using Laravel and PhpUnit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Lets say I have a system, build with Laravel and used for displaying different restaurants and It has a standard filter , that checks for all restaurants that have the given filter criteria.
Every restaurant holds properties:

- has_wifi;  can_pay_with_card;  has_parking;  is_pet_friendly

| Restaurant | Wifi | Card Pay | Parking | Pet Friendly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| R 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| R 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

and there is filter, that uses those same properties.

(**Wifi**) (Card Pay) (Parking) (Pet Friendly) -> R1, R3

(**Wifi**) (Card Pay) (**Parking**) (Pet Friendly) -> R3

Currently I am writing tests using PHPUnit and for what I understand, I should check all input possibilities for the given filter and compare the returned subset of data.

(**Wifi**) (Card Pay) (Parking) (Pet Friendly)

(**Wifi**) (**Card Pay**) (Parking) (Pet Friendly)

(**Wifi**) (**Card Pay**) (**Parking**) (Pet Friendly)

…..

(Wifi) (**Card Pay**) (**Parking**) (Pet Friendly)

….

(Wifi) (Card Pay) (Parking) (**Pet Friendly**)

For the base case, where I should check only for places with wifi for example, I can do the following:

```
public function testFilterByWifiWithPlaces()
{
    $body = $this->requestParameters([
        'wifi' => 1,
    ]);

    $this->json(
        'POST',
        $this->baseUrl . self::SEARCH_PLACES_ENDPOINT,
        $body,
        $this->requestHeaders()
    )->seeJsonStructure([
        'id',
        'code',
        'data' => [
            'places' => [
                '*' => $this->dataObject->getStructure()
            ],
        ]
    ])->seeJson([
    'id' => $this->placeWithWifi->place_key,
    'name' => $this->placeWithWifi->default_name]);
}
```

BUT given the data that I have and the dual possibility of the values, using separate methods like
`testFilterByWifiWithPlaces()`, `testFilterByWifiAndParkingWithPlaces()`,… (all possibilities),… is not an valid option for sure!

My approach to the problem is the following:

- Creating a array holding instances of all possible objects with
  different property combinations
- Accessing them via keys: ex: `$testRestaurants[‘with_wifi][’no_card_pay’][‘with_parking][’no_pet_friendly’]`
  -> Restaurant object
- Looping through all $testRestaurants and executing above mentioned logic, knowing the state of the filter from keys given

I am not sure if i am on the right track. This seems as a problem that many people should’ve faced, taking in consideration the large amount of filter engines existing on the internet :D Still , I wonder is there easiest way to test this kind of large set with data with many possibilities?